# Type Error: 'list' object is not callable while calculating the roc curve

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

```
def multiclass_roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro"):
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()

    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_pred[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
        
    # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
    fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_pred.ravel())
    roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
    
    
#     # Plot of a ROC curve for a specific class
#     for i in range(n_classes):
#         plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
#         plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[i])
#         plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
#         plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
#         plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
#         plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
#         plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
#         plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
#         plt.legend(loc="lower right")
#         plt.show()


    # First aggregate all false positive rates
    all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

    # Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
    mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
    for i in range(n_classes):
        mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

    # Finally average it and compute AUC
    mean_tpr /= n_classes

    fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
    tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
    roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

    # Plot all ROC curves
    plt.figure(figsize=(21,21))
    plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
         label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]),
         color='deeppink', linestyle=':', linewidth=lw)

    plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],
         label='macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["macro"]),
         color='navy', linestyle=':', linewidth=lw)

    colors = cycle(['navy', 'turquoise', 'darkorange', 'cornflowerblue', 'teal'])
    for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
        plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
            label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
             ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate', fontsize = 25)
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate', fontsize = 25)
    plt.title('ROC and AUC Curve', fontsize = 25)
    plt.legend(loc="lower right",fontsize='xx-large')
    plt.show()
        
    return roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, average=average)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7244/4198522018.py in <module>
     71     return roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, average=average)
     72 
---> 73 print("ROC_AUC_Score:", multiclass_roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred))

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7244/4198522018.py in multiclass_roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, average)
      6     for i in range(n_classes):
      7         fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_pred[:, i])
----> 8         roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
      9 
     10     # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
    
    print("ROC_AUC_Score:", multiclass_roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

I am getting this running this code on my jyputer notebook.
Can anyone resolve this error

Comment: Maybe you have named in your code a list `auc`, thereby shadowing the function `auc()`.

Comment: Please show where/how `auc` is defined or imported. And, as Mr T says, check carefully if it might have been defined more than once, only the last definition will still be effective.